# Defining Field names with special characters such as ^ in python dbf

Tags: python, dbf

I want to define a DBF table with field names which may contain ^ character. 
I am using the following table definition:

```
tbl_SubDBF = dbf.Table("..//output//Ttest.dbf", \
                       'B^AWG C(50);    C^PTYPE C(200)')
```

I am getting a fieldspecerror as following:

```
field names must start with a letter, and can only contain letters, digits, and _
```

Is there a workaround (escape character) which allows me to define the headers mentioned above while creating dbf table?

I am using python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

To the best of my knowledge, the dbf field spec does not allow for non-alphanumeric characters in field names.  The only possible work-around at the moment is to subclass `Table` and replace the failing method with one that allows the strange characters.

---

**Updated Answer**

Looking at the method in question (`add_fields`), replacing it would be a major endeavor.  So as of `dbf 0.98.0` one can use whatever strange characters one wants/needs in fields names, but dbf will generate a warning about it:

```
<module>:<line_no>: FieldNameWarning: "p^type invalid:  field names should start with a letter, and only contain letters, digits, and _
some_dbf.add_fields('p^type C(25)')
```

To suppress that warning one can add:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '', dbf.FieldNameWarning)
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I don't know how to do the above, I was thinking writing a function and explicitly renaming the field name with C^ would work, perhaps there is some direction that I can follow there instead of doing a class-subclass coding etc (I've not done any programming or modification in classes)

Comment: Once I create a DBF table, I can open it in its program and can rename the columns, its just a manual step that I'd prefer to avoid. 
After table creation and field names adjustment, I am implementing a large number of automated tasks for the user and wouldn't prefer for them to pause and make manual adjustments to the table field

Comment: @MakJ:  Instead of `C^` can you use `C_`?  Are you using any other programs besides Python and `dbf` to process these files?  If so, can they work with field names that have `^` in them?

Comment: Yes that is indeed the limitation, The header field needs to have C^Cbl name. The program which then reads this table identifies C^ as pointing to a built in catalog instead of treating it as text. There is no alternative, a few header fields have to be exported with C^ which DBF doesn't allow. So... any other ideas?

Comment: @MakJ:  Updated answer.  Short version: get the latest version of `dbf`.  :)